# Unity minus extra number when I just want minus one

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What I'm trying to do is when it hits a triggered collider I want it to minus an `int`, but what unity does is minus it with 3 instead, and I have it attached to the player itself

```
lifecontroller lves;
public GameObject gm;
CoinScript coins;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    gm = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GM");
    coins = gm.GetComponent<CoinScript>();
    lves = gm.GetComponent<lifecontroller>();
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if(other.tag == "Evil")
    {
        lves.lives -= 1;
        Debug.Log("U hit it");
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if(lves.lives == 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("u died");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is fine. You likely have this script attached to other gameobjects.

Comment: no its not i even re write it

Comment: How many "U hit it" logs you can see in console window. One thing for sure is that having this script is not a problem here. You probably have this script more than once on your player.

Comment: put to get the script  to work it needs to be attached to the player or it wont work

Comment: and i checked every object it wasnt there :/

Comment: Select the script, right click on it and click "Find References In Scene". You will ever GameObject the script is attache to. If there is more than 1, the that is your problem

Comment: https://gyazo.com/42c7ca7bb59d0bae0add6b0f7de95297

Comment: look its not screenhoted it

Comment: @FatihTkale change the log statement in the `OnTriggerMerhod` to `Debug.Log("U hit it", other.gameObject);` and click on log from console to check which object its hitting.

Comment: @UmairM it just gave me a error

Comment: fixed it + was needed

Comment: So that was the problem? Attached to the Player multiple times?

Comment: no didnt fix the problem itself

Answer (score 4):

Judging from the screenshot, your script is attached to the **Player** GameObject multiple times. Select your Player GameObject, and remove the duplicate Script.
Make sure there is only one script attached to it. It is probably attached there **3** times.

This problem can also happen if you are instantiating multiple Player GameObjects during run-time as this will duplicate your script too.

[image]

**EDIT**:

With the updated Image in your comment, the problem is that you have **3** Colliders on your Player. It is true that only one of them is made `IsTrigger` but this is a problem if the GameObject with the **Evil** tag is marked as `IsTrigger` too.

You have **2** options to fix this:

**1**.Select the GameObjects with the **Evil** tag and make sure that no Collider attached to it is marked as `IsTrigger`. Unceheck all `IsTrigger` properties on the Collider of all **Evil** tagged GameObjects **only**. This should fix your problem.

2.Only have one Collider on Player GameObject. Remove the other 2. This again should fix your problem.

Comment: as i said multiple times its not attached multiple times :p

Comment: You said it is fixed in the comment section. So what was the problem?  What fixed it?

Comment: no it wasnt that it was something someone lese said

Comment: I found your problem after looking at your image. I was able to replicate your problem with those settings.Scroll down on my answer and  Check the edit in it. You have 2 options to solve the problem. Let me know the outcome.

Comment: Thanks it worked the collider was the problem thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) answer if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

The trigger is definitly happening 3 times, your screenshot shows that (there is a 3 on the right since duplicate logs get collapsed).

This might occur because of the collider shape I think (circle). Try using a bool that us set on trigger enter and clear on trigger exit (or even Update should be ok for clearing).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I suggested to debug your problem:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if(other.tag == "Evil")
    {
        lves.lives -= 1;
        Debug.Log("U hit it", other.gameObject);
    }
}
```

And by looking at your screenshot you are getting 3 log messages.

**Always use don't collapse in console window to see whats happening**

[image]

Comment: i know there is no diffrent

Comment: And this has nothing to do with the problem

Comment: Obviously! no one can know the original problem except you. I just tried to explain how to debug it. you can see there are 3 log messages. What does that mean? and if you un-collapse the messages and clicking on each of them will highlight the object which is causing the trigger. And if you are destroying the evil object in other scripts it wont highlight anything. Again, no can else solve this kind of problem but just point you in right direction. Happy coding!